# simple twitter bootstrap fluid layout span5 != span5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following example where the last TWO paragraphs at the bottom are span5 but don't match the span 10 above them AND don't match the span5's that are above that span10 either.

http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/2959/

Add snippet of code so stackoverflow let's me post(how stupid)....stackoverflow actually errors out saying must paste jsfiddle code here which just seems dumb to me since it is piece with lots of text in it.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [twitter bootstrap docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem):

Fluid grids utilize nesting differently: each nested level of columns should **add up to 12 columns**. This is because the fluid grid uses percentages, not pixels, for setting widths.

Answer (score 3):

When using row-fluid the contents have to add up to 12.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
    Fluid 12
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span6">
        Fluid 6
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span6">Fluid 6</div>
          <div class="span6">Fluid 6</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="span6">Fluid 6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: More specifically, your ```border-right: 1px``` is probably pushing the width over 12.

Comment: `span*` does not work with bootstrap 3. Is it only for bootstrap 2? Is there any alternative in bootstrap 3? Thanks