# Bootstrap column span regardless of screen size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid

In bootstrap, we can use `.col-xs-*`,`.col-sm-*`,`.col-md-*`,`.col-lg-*` to span `*` columns depending on screen size.

I'm looking for a css class that allows me to span `*` columns regardless of screen size. Something like:

```
<div class="col-all-5">
</div>
```

Looks like it's possible with `span*`: [simple twitter bootstrap fluid layout span5 != span5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671269/simple-twitter-bootstrap-fluid-layout-span5-span5/15671332#comment53397408_15671332). But I don't know why it does not work on my project. Is it because it's only for bootstrap 2? Is there alternative in bootstrap 3?

At the moment, I'm fixing the issue by using all the css classes for all screen sizes, it looks like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
</div>
```

It's not optimal because there are a lot of duplicates.

Comment: In bootstrap 3, you should be able to achieve by using only `col-xs-5` did you try that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bootstrap 3, you should be able to achieve by using only `col-xs-5`

- See this **demo** - http://jsbin.com/foxefudiwi/edit?html,output

#### Explanation

If you look into bootstrap 3 code (think they changed in bootstrap 4 alpha), they dont apply the media queries to the `xs` columns - and therefore dont alter the `xs` classes when the viewport width changes.

e.g. they setup the column definitions [line 1616 in the unminified "dist" CSS](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L1616)

#### col basic styling

```
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

tell the `xs` columns to float alongside each other

```
.col-xs-1, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12 {
  float: left;
}
```

After that (I think) the `xs` columns get pretty much left alone - *the other* column sizes get media queries which alter (basically lose the float) above breakpoint.

Comment: yes, that should be the way to achieve mobile first